# XSLT 2.0 xsl:value-of separator attribute not working in Java 1.7 with apache.xalan

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

The XSLT 2.0 **xsl:value-of** element **separator** attribute appears to not be working with the built-in Java 1.7 XSLT processor. Here's the example (slightly edited from Chapter 4 of [XSLT 2nd ed.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527211.do) to reduce size):

## XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cars>
    <manufacturer name="Chevrolet">
    </manufacturer>
    <manufacturer name="Ford">
    </manufacturer>
    <manufacturer name="Volkswagen">
    </manufacturer>
</cars>
```

## XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:value-of select="cars/manufacturer/@name" separator=", "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Java code

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class FooMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        System.out.println("transformer factory class: "+factory.getClass()); // line-a
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);                                                                                                                                                                     
        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.html")));
    }
}
```

When the code runs, it produces the following output file:

```
Chevrolet
```

... as opposed to what the book describes:

```
Chevrolet, Ford, Volkswagen
```

I am using Java 1.7 in Ubuntu Precise and the classname of the **TransformerFactory** instance is reported (in *line-a* of the Java code above) as:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

## UPDATE

I experimented and renamed the **separator** attribute in the **XSLT** file to **separatorBOO** and the code continues to run without complaining and produces the exact same output. So it would seem that the XSLT 2.0 **separator** attribute is not recognized at all ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide another factory as Xalan does not support xslt2 transformations.
Try to use Saxon. I guess you only have to drop the jar into your classpath as Java is using it's embedded version if there's no provider in the classpath.

Comment: Yeap, putting saxon9he.jar in the runtime classpath did the trick

Comment: is saxon the only lib that supports xslt2 transformations??